# Invoke-WebRequest timeout if NIC 1 disconnected

Tags: powershell

I have a Windows PC with three network interfaces. One is a UMTS modem and the two others are local networks and one network has connection to the internet.

Invoke-WebRequest http://192.168.1.118/File1.xml

As long as I have an internet connection, either via UMTS or via the second network the Invoke-WebRequest works. But if I only have a connection to one local network, I get a timeout, although pinging the address is still working.

Where might be the problem? Or is it possible to define the network interface where the webrequest should try to get data?

Comment: Sounds like routing or name resolution problem, so this is more releated to Superuser or Serverfault.

Comment: Do you have a proxy configured on this box ? `[System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebproxy()`

Comment: The proxy was configuered. As soon as i disabled the proxy it worked. Can you post your answer so i can accept it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a proxy configured on this box ?

`[System.Net.WebRequest]::GetSystemWebproxy()`

You can try to disable it, so you should have a direct acces to your intranet.